# how to carry my HTC Desire on me? no bag, no pocket

Tags: htc-desire

In winter time I used to carry my HTC Desire in my jacket's pocket...

It's summer time now :-) and I have no pocket (I don't want to use my jeans pocket) and I don't carry any bags on me when going to work.

I was thinking of carry my Desire **around my neck** but how can I do that? What is **the safe** way to do so?

Comment: I have a similar problem; there's no gap to tie a strap onto on the HTC Desire Z. Seems a major omission, particularly when distributing in the UK where phones get grabbed out of hands on a frequent basis - it's nice to have a strap around your wrist to make phone-snatching a little more difficult.

Comment: I thought this question was a joke when I first saw it, but looking at the Desire and Desire Z manuals I can't believe they missed off the hook for the wrist strap, I thought that was a standard feature on phones for years!

Comment: @GAThrawn - I'm REALLY missing a hang-up button. I'm never buying another phone without a hang-up button ever again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Desire does not have a strap hole, then perhaps you might be able to find a phone case that have an attachment for neck strap.

If there is no such case, you might be able to find a cheap silicone case, and punch a hole in it.

Alternatively, if you wears a belt, some phone cases attaches to your belt.

Comment: acutally I am using silicone case already. Wasn't sure if the making hole is safe. I don't want the phone fall on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the plastic ring (part of a main black panel piece) around a 3.5 jack to tie a strap. You may need to cut the grooves for the strap in the back panel to be tightly attached after that. Sure way to void a warranty due to an "alteration" or s "mechanical damage".